# Ho to setup Test class execution in release pipeline for salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a class and test class related to Salesforce to migrate to the target environment.
from QA environment to the User acceptance environment. The developer's request is not to run the test class skip the test class execution for that particular deployment, he will fix it later. I could not find a way to set up to Skip the test class execution and vice-versa.

pls help

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to deploy?

Apache Ant + "Migration Tool" - look for build.xml file and in it you should have something similar to this:

```
<target name="deployCode">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"
        sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
        deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunLocalTests">
    </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

(might depend on how you pass variables, they key is the `sf:deploy` thing). Delete the `testLevel` part to get default behaviour (no tests in sandboxes but run all local tests in prod). You can use NoTestRun, RunSpecifiedTests, RunLocalTests or RunAllTestsInOrg. More info: https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf (html version of developer docs seems to be down now)

If you work with SFDX CLI the command you have is probably something like `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f ../unpackaged.zip -u myUserAlias -l RunLocalTests`. Same idea, remove the `l RunLocalTests` to get default behaviour.